# Set each column of grid view to different width

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview which contains template fields and I want to set different widths for each column. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width of the column in width attribute of the template columns as,

```
<asp:TemplateField FooterText="ADD">
                    <ControlStyle Height="10px" Width="20px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```